# Failed to connected database its showing connection failedSQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ecom'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have reinstalled wamp server and getting this error.Im   using php pdo to connect with database
here is my code

```
<?php 

 class Database{
      private $dbname="mysql:host=localhost; dbname=ecom;";
      private $dbuser="root";
      private $dbpass="";
      public $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->conn)){
            try {
                $this->conn= new PDO("$this->dbname,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass");
                $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die("connection failed".$e->getMessage());
            }
        }
     }
    

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php 

 class Database{
      private $dbname="mysql:host=localhost; dbname=ecom;";
      private $dbuser="root";
      private $dbpass="";
      public $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->conn)){
            try {
                $this->conn= new PDO($this->dbname,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass);
                $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die("connection failed".$e->getMessage());
            }
        }
     }
    

}

?>
```